# Google Play Games Service is failing on .Create() with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c++, ant, android-ndk, visual-studio-2017, google-play-games

I am working on a game that is in C++ on Android using Visual Studio 2017 and Ant build system. I am trying to hook up the Google Play Services for leader boards but the `gpg::GameServices::Builder().Create` is failing with:

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;

Other info:
The min SDK is 22
The NDK is r15c
ANT is 1.9.3

I have linked the libgpg.a lib to my project. 
I have a OAuth2.0 client ID.

I have even set up a obb download from GooglePlay and that works fine. Is there another library or jar that I am missing? I have followed the steps here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/GettingStartedNativeClient